# How to set navbar color and size of cells inside a tab bar controller when 'more' button is pressed?

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I currently have a tab bar controller that has numerous navigation controllers inside it.  I can set the nav controller color inside most of the viewcontrollers except when the 'more' button is pressed on the tab view controller (bottom corner tab):

[image]

Once the more button is pressed it doesn't go to a view controller I created, it goes to some set view controller that's associated with the tab bar:

[image]

I'm trying to change the color of the nav bar inside this "more" tab to black and the size of the cells (for card and settings) to make them larger.  Typically I would do this in a viewDidLoad but since the view is created by the tab bar I am not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out part of the answer to change the navigation bar.  I subclassed the tab bar and inside my viewDidLoad I changed the moreNavigationController attributes like this:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

    moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackOpaque
    moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }
```

it was able to make the nav bar black.  I still haven't found out a way to change the cells' size inside the moreNavigationController yet.